useColorScheme works for iOS but not for Android
I have a React Native app on Android and iOS. The code for both apps are the same. I am using useColorScheme from "react-native" to automatically detect the user's light/dark theme and apply it to the app. For some reason, the useColorsScheme is working on my iOS app but not on my Android despite using the same code. It doesn't work on the Android simulator nor on my Android physical device.
Does anybody know how to fix this? This is my app.json file, styles.xml and colors.xml files. I initially changed the app.json and that didn't work. Then, I also changed the styles.xml and colors.xml files and that didn't work either.
// app.json  
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "XXX",
    "slug": "XXX",
    "version": "1.2.3",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "ios": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    }
  }
}

// styles.xml in /android/app/src/main/res/values
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/ResetEditText</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ResetEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#c8c8c8</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
  </style>
</resources>

// colors.xml in /android/app/src/main/res/values-night
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">  </style>
</resources>```


I have already searched on Stackoverflow changing my app.json, styles.xml and values.xml files. It didn't work yet.


What is the response you get from useColorScheme if you log it?, it has to response something at least
